# C semaphore and shared memory

Tags: c, system-calls, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm trying to develop the classic producer-consumer circular buffer example with one producer and one consumer respectively.

However I'm having some problems that I can't figure out where they come from.
In particular the producer seems to work but the consumer always picks up a 0.
I was thinking about some problem with shared memory and/or buffering but they seem to be implemented correctly

Code explanation:

-Initially I create the shared memory area of ​​the size of the STRUCT_BUFFER defined above. It is actually only used to provide the size at this point.

-I create 3 semaphores: mutex, full, empty.

-fork(): in the child (consumer) I call a get of the data on the buffer and if the number found is -1 (termination token) it puts it back and exits the loop, terminating. In the parent (producer) I execute a for which puts each index on the buffer respectively and at the end puts a -1 (termination token).

-Then wait until the consumers are finished and eliminate the traffic lights.
The get and put functions are the classic codes of producer-consumers.

ps. SYSC() macro is only used for error management.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define SHM_NAME "/shm8"
#define MUTEX "/mutex"
#define FULL "/full"
#define EMPTY "/empty"

#define N 10
#define SYSC(value, command, message) if ((value=command) == -1){perror(message); exit(errno);}
#define SYSCN(value, command, message) if ((value=command) == NULL){perror(message); exit(errno);}

typedef struct{
    int B[N];
    int *head;
    int *tail;
} STRUCT_BUFFER;

void put(int, int*, int*, int*, sem_t*, sem_t*, sem_t*);
int get(int*, int*, int*, sem_t*, sem_t*, sem_t*);

int main(){
     
    int ret_value, mem_fd;
    void * ptr;
    pid_t pid;
    sem_t * mutex;
    sem_t * full;
    sem_t * empty;
    int * head;
    int * tail;

    // Creating shared memory area
    SYSC(mem_fd, shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666), "in shm_open");
    SYSC(ret_value, ftruncate(mem_fd, sizeof(STRUCT_BUFFER)), "in ftruncate");

    // Memory mapping
    SYSCN(ptr, mmap(NULL, sizeof(STRUCT_BUFFER), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, mem_fd, 0), "in mmap");
    head = tail = ptr;

    // Closing file descriptor
    SYSC(ret_value, close(mem_fd), "in close");

    // Creating semaphores
    mutex = sem_open(MUTEX, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);
    if(mutex == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("In sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    full = sem_open(FULL, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, N);
    if(full == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("In sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    empty = sem_open(EMPTY, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);
    if(empty == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("In sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Creating a new process
    SYSC(pid, fork(), "in fork");

    if(!pid) {
        // Consumer code
        printf("Consumer %d starts\n", getpid());

        int toGet;
        while(1) {
            toGet = get(ptr, head, tail, mutex, full, empty);
            printf("Consumer %d consumed %d\n", getpid(), toGet);
            
            // If termination token
            if(toGet == -1) {
                put(toGet, ptr, head, tail, mutex, full, empty);
                break;
            }
        }

        sleep(1);
        printf("Consumer %d finishes\n",getpid());
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    } else {
        // Producer code
        printf("Producer %d starts\n",getpid());

        int toPut;
        int exitToken = -1;

        // Production
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
            toPut = i + 1;
            put(toPut, ptr, head, tail, mutex, full, empty);
            printf("Producer %d produced %d. Cycle:%d\n", getpid(), toPut, i);
            sleep(1);            
        }

        // Termination token
        put(exitToken, ptr, head, tail, mutex, full, empty);
        printf("Producer %d produced termination token\n", getpid());
        sleep(1);

        // Wait
        SYSC(ret_value, wait(NULL), "in wait");
        
        // Closing semaphores
        sem_close(mutex);
        sem_close(empty);
        sem_close(full);

        sem_unlink(MUTEX);
        sem_unlink(FULL);
        sem_unlink(EMPTY);

        // Closing shared memory
        munmap(ptr, sizeof(STRUCT_BUFFER));

        printf("Producer %d finishes\n",getpid());
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    }

}

void put(int toPut, int * ptr, int * head, int * tail, sem_t * mutex, sem_t * full, sem_t * empty) {
    
    sem_wait(full);
    sem_wait(mutex);

    // Critical section
    ptr[*tail] = toPut;
    *tail = ((*tail) + 1) % N;

    sem_post(mutex);
    sem_post(empty);
}

int get(int * ptr, int * head, int * tail, sem_t * mutex, sem_t * full, sem_t * empty) {

    sem_wait(empty);
    sem_wait(mutex);
    
    // Critical section
    int toGet;
    toGet = ptr[*head];
    *head = ((*head) + 1) % N;

    sem_post(mutex);
    sem_post(full);

    return toGet;
}
```

Comment: If you want help with program behavior, then folks need to be able to see the entire program.  Can you inline SYSC's definition  or remove it?

Comment: Since you're setting up a shared memory region anyway, why not make it large enough for as many semaphores as you need, too, and use anonymous (process-shared) semaphores stored there?  That will at least sidestep any issues that might arise from your named semaphores surviving abnornal termination of your program, or from multiple instances of your program running concurrently.

Comment: Each process is using its own local copies of the `head` and `tail` pointers, not the ones for which you've reserved space in shared memory.  That's almost ok, because `put()` uses only the tail pointer and `get()` uses only the head pointer, but then the consumer spoils it by calling `put()`.  But this does not explain why the consumer is reading zeroes.

Comment: For those problems I prefer queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having inferred suitable definitions for your `SYSC` and `SYSCN` macros, I was able to build your program and confirm your observed misbehavior.

The primary error is to do with the `head` and `tail` pointers.  When you declare them as pointers in `main` and initialize them like so:

> ```
>     head = tail = ptr;
> ```

, you are treating them as if they are pointers to the head and tail elements of the buffer themselves.  It would be ok in that case for the head and tail pointers to initially alias each other and the base pointer.

In your `get()` and `put()` functions, however, you are treating `head` and `tail` as pointers to variables storing the *indices* of the head and tail elements.  For example:

> ```
>     ptr[*tail] = toPut;
>     *tail = ((*tail) + 1) % N;
> ```

For that use, it is *not* ok for those pointers to alias each other or the data.  They need then to point to their own, separate objects.

As a secondary matter, the `head` and `tail` indices (`int`s, not pointers) need to be shared between the processes, because the consumer process accesses both.  In the original code, the `head` and `tail` pointers used are both local variables of `main`, and so not shared between processes (each process has its own, independent copies of these).  It looks like you might have planned to share the pointers via the shared `STRUCT_BUFFER` object, but ended up not doing so.  This would be an appropriate place to put the head and tail indices that you need to share.

Additionally, I would recommend

- using an anonymous memory mapping instead of creating and mapping a POSIX shared memory segment.  Aside from being simpler, that will eliminate issues that could arise from the shared memory segment living longer than you intended / needed or being shared by distinct instances of your program running concurrently.
- using unnamed (process-shared) semaphores stored in the shared memory region instead of named semaphores.  This is slightly simpler, and eliminates issues that could arise from your semaphores living longer than you intended or being shared  by distinct instances of your program running concurrently.  These object would need to be stored in shared memory, but you already have a setup for that.  Just add these to `STRUCT_BUFFER`.
- having implemented all of the above, your `STRUCT_BUFFER` object will contain all the information the `get()` and `put()` functions need to work with, other than the particular value that `put()` should store.  I strongly recommend modifying these functions to accept a pointer to the `STRUCT_BUFFER` instead of all those individual arguments.

Comment: I tried defining int *Head = ptr + N and int *Tail = ptr + N+1, so they point to the last two shared memory cells that contain the actual head and tail values.
However, the problem persists, in particular I noticed that the producer always writes only to the first shared memory cell, in fact the tail value is always reset to 0 every time the put function is called. It is incremented to 1 in the put function but then returns to 0 in the next invocation. I don't understand why since the pointers are always the same and the head and tail values ​​reside in shared memory.

Comment: @Grinza, I can't speak to the specific changes you describe based on that description alone.  But in case it was unclear, I assure you that implementing the changes described in this answer fixed the problem for me.  I urge you in particular to get rid of the `head` and `tail` pointers altogether, put all the objects you want to share in the `STRUCT_BUFFER`, as members, and implement at least the third of my supplemental recommendations.  To be absolutely clear, the `STRUCT_BUFFER` would contain the head and tail *indices*, directly, not pointers to these.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#include "macros.h"

#define SHM_NAME "/shm111"
#define MUTEX "/mutex"
#define FULL "/full"
#define EMPTY "/empty"

#define N 10

typedef struct{
    int B[N];
    int head;
    int tail;
} STRUCT_BUFFER;

void put(int, STRUCT_BUFFER*, sem_t*, sem_t*, sem_t*);
int get(STRUCT_BUFFER*, sem_t*, sem_t*, sem_t*);

int main(){
     
    int ret_value, mem_fd;
    pid_t pid;
    sem_t * mutex;
    sem_t * full;
    sem_t * empty;
    STRUCT_BUFFER *buf;

    // Creating shared memory area
    SYSC(mem_fd, shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, 0666), "in shm_open");
    SYSC(ret_value, ftruncate(mem_fd, sizeof(STRUCT_BUFFER)), "in ftruncate");

    // Memory mapping
    SYSCN(buf, (STRUCT_BUFFER*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(STRUCT_BUFFER), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, mem_fd, 0), "in mmap");
    buf->head = 0;
    buf->tail = 0;

    // Closing fd
    SYSC(ret_value, close(mem_fd), "in close");

    // Creating semaphores
    mutex = sem_open(MUTEX, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);
    if(mutex == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("In sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    full = sem_open(FULL, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, N);
    if(full == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("In sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    empty = sem_open(EMPTY, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);
    if(empty == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("In sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Creating a new process
    SYSC(pid, fork(), "in fork");

    if(!pid) {
        // Consumer code
        printf("Consumer %d starts\n",getpid());

        int toGet;
        while(1) {
            toGet = get(buf, mutex, full, empty);
            printf("Consumer %d consumed %d\n", getpid(), toGet);
            
            // If termination token
            if(toGet == -1) {
                put(toGet, buf, mutex, full, empty);
                break;
            }
        }

        sleep(1);
        printf("Consumer %d ends\n",getpid());
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    } else {
        // Producer code
        printf("Producer %d starts\n",getpid());

        int toPut;
        int exitToken = -1;

        // Production
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
            toPut = i + 1;
            put(toPut, buf, mutex, full, empty);

            printf("Producer %d produced %d. Cycle:%d\n", getpid(), toPut, i);
            sleep(1);            
        }

        // Termination token
        put(exitToken, buf, mutex, full, empty);
        printf("Producer %d produced termination token\n", getpid());
        sleep(1);

        // Wait
        SYSC(ret_value, wait(NULL), "in wait");
        
        // Closing semaphores
        sem_close(mutex);
        sem_close(empty);
        sem_close(full);

        sem_unlink(MUTEX);
        sem_unlink(FULL);
        sem_unlink(EMPTY);

        // Closing shared memory
        munmap(buf, sizeof(STRUCT_BUFFER));

        printf("Producer %d ends\n",getpid());
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    }

}

void put(int toPut, STRUCT_BUFFER* buf, sem_t * mutex, sem_t * full, sem_t * empty) {
    
    sem_wait(full);
    sem_wait(mutex);

    // Critical section
    buf->B[buf->tail] = toPut;
    buf->tail = ((buf->tail) + 1) % N;
    sem_post(mutex);
    sem_post(empty);
}

int get(STRUCT_BUFFER* buf, sem_t * mutex, sem_t * full, sem_t * empty) {

    sem_wait(empty);
    sem_wait(mutex);
    
    // Critical section
    int toGet;
    toGet = buf->B[buf->head];
    buf->head = ((buf->head + 1) % N);

    sem_post(mutex);
    sem_post(full);

    return toGet;
}
```